# Replit env not working for discord token?

Tags: python, discord, environment-variables

```
import os
import discord
intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.messages = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("The {0.user} bot has logged in".format(client))


client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN')
```

It's giving me "Improper token has been passed" even though it's not an improper token. If I just put the regular token in directly, it just starts working

I tried searching for an answer and inputting different syntax but that didn't work. I also tried making an env file instead of a secret.

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if your .env file is linked or not with your bot [Put this code in **config.py**]:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv

__all__ = [
    "Auth"
]

load_dotenv(
    find_dotenv(filename="file_name.env", raise_error_if_not_found=True),
    verbose=True,
)

class Auth:
    TOKEN = os.environ["TOKEN"]
```

Put your token in **file_name.env**

TOKEN = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

Try to put below code in your main.py file

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    client.run(Auth.TOKEN)
```